# Object spread doesn't copy the object properly

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, es6-class

I am having a strange issue using object spread. Here is my code:

```
const AuthenticationReducer = (state = {
authenticationObj: {
    "isAuthenticating": true, "isAuthentic": false, "subscriberId": "NA", "username": "NA",
    "firstName": "NA", "lastName": "NA", "enabled": "1", "email": "NA", isAuthorized: false
}, lastPasswordCheckStatus: undefined, isSuccessfulChangePassword:undefined,loginUserCheckStatus: undefined, createUserCheckstatus: undefined,
confirmUserCheckstatus: undefined, isSuccessfulChangeEmail:undefined, userContactInfo: {
    country: undefined,
    address1:undefined,
    address2:undefined,
    city:undefined,
    postalCode:undefined,
    phoneNumber: undefined
}
 }, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USER_CONTACT_INFO:
        console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
        state = {
            ...state,
            authenticationObj: {
                ...state.authenticationObj, userContactInfo: action.payload.userContactInfo
            }
        };
        console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
        console.log(action.payload.userContactInfo);

}
return state;
 };
    export default AuthenticationReducer;
```

Before SET_USER_CONTACT_INFO call the state is as follows:

```
{
"authenticationObj": {
    "isAuthenticating": false,
    "isAuthentic": true,
    "subscriberId": 4424,
    "username": "cccc",
    "firstName": "null",
    "lastName": "null",
    "email": "cccc",
    "isAuthorized": true
},
"userContactInfo": {}
}
```

As you see "userContactInfo": {} is empty object which make sense now as soon as SET_USER_CONTACT_INFO request is  dispatched I get:

```
{
"authenticationObj": {
    "isAuthenticating": false,
    "isAuthentic": true,
    "subscriberId": 4424,
    "username": "vvvv",
    "firstName": "null",
    "lastName": "null",
    "email": "vvv",
    "isAuthorized": true,
    "userContactInfo": {
        "country": "Canada",
        "address1": "ssss",
        "address2": "sss",
        "city": "ssss",
        "postalCode": "ss",
        "phoneNumber": "sss"
    }
  },
    "userContactInfo": {}
 }
```

I get both userContactInfo one empty and one with info. It is really strange I expect the userContactInfo with new info is replaced with the empty one. what is wrong with my code? any help?

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508) . And this has nothing to do with JSX or React or redux.

Comment: @FelixKling thanx I fixed the wording

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I expect the userContactInfo with new info is replaced with the empty one.

The two `userContactInfo` are on different levels. One is at the top level, *next to* `authenticationObj`, the other is in the value of `authenticationObj` itself, which you easily see by looking at the indentation. Besides, an object cannot have two properties with the same name.

```
{
  "authenticationObj": {
    "isAuthenticating": false,
    "isAuthentic": true,
    "subscriberId": 4424,
    "username": "vvvv",
    "firstName": "null",
    "lastName": "null",
    "email": "vvv",
    "isAuthorized": true,
    "userContactInfo": {         // <root>.authenticationObj.userContactInfo
      "country": "Canada",
      "address1": "ssss",
      "address2": "sss",
      "city": "ssss",
      "postalCode": "ss",
      "phoneNumber": "sss"
    }
  },
  "userContactInfo": {}          // <root>.userContactInfo
}
```

I.e. you are merging the object on the wrong level. Seems what you want is

```
state = {
  ...state,
  userContactInfo: action.payload.userContactInfo
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This:
        state = {
            ...state,
            authenticationObj: {
                ...state.authenticationObj, 
                userContactInfo: action.payload.userContactInfo
            }
        };

Should be:
        state = {
            ...state,
          userContactInfo: {
                ...state.userContactInfo
                 action.payload.userContactInfo
          }
        };

You have told the script to insert the action.payload.userContactInfo into the authenticationObj, whereas it should placed as a sibling to it.

Sorry it's short I've wrote this on my phone.